# No errors in code but the program stopped working

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am using code blocks and it says my code has no errors, Yet when I run the program it stopped working as I tried to give an input. Please keep in mind that my programming class has just started and I do not know much at all.

Here is the code to my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int num;
int num1, num2, num3, num4;

printf("Please insert a number here:\n");
scanf("%d\n", num);

printf("When value of variable num is 2,\n");
num1 = num +1;
printf("\nThe value of num after using num + 1 is: %d", num1);
num2 = num +=1;
printf("\nThe value of num after using num +=1 is: %d", num2);
num3 = ++num;
printf("\nThe value of num after using ++num is: %d", num3);
num4 = num++;
printf("\nThe value of num after using num++ is: %d", num4);

return 0;

}
```

and when I run the program it stopped working.

So, how can I fix this error? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code as text here

Comment: (The error is that a & is missing at scanf. The compiler won´t show you all errors, sadly; but this IS an error)

Comment: Thanks a whole lot. It's due soon so I'm glad you answered. Also, can I know why ans3 and ans4 becomes 4 and not three? Did the value of num change halfway? How do I prevent that?

Comment: @user3162312 You are changing `num` at line 9, 12, 14, and 16 and to show the different effects is probably the whole point of this code. You should read up on this basic stuff in a book or your lecture notes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user link to screenshot of short code (< 20 lines) instead of posting the code as text.

Comment: So, how do i prevent the change of num in line 12? I need all the answers to be be a number added by 1. So if num is 2, I need the answers to be 3. I can thank you enough.

Comment: `scanf("%d\n", &num)` `float` --> `int`

Comment: Actually there is no need to use `float` at all.

Comment: @nisyedlah Thank you for posting the code as text now, but you shouldn't correct the errors others pointed out, because people reading this won't understand anymore. Please write down the original code.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in the **scanf** call.

It should be

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Note the & before num. Scanf expects a pointer to the variable that have to be filled in with the input value.

---

Regarding your code and the question in your comment you should note that:

```
num1 = num +1;
```

**num1** is **num** plus one

```
printf("\nThe value of num after using num + 1 is: %d", num1);
num2 = num +=1;
```

**num** is incremented by 1 then assigned to **num2** with the new value

```
printf("\nThe value of num after using num +=1 is: %d", num2);
num3 = ++num;
```

**num** is again incremented by 1 and then assigned to **num3**

```
printf("\nThe value of num after using ++num is: %d", num3);
num4 = num++;
```

**num** at its actual value is assigned to **num4** *then* **num** is incremented by 1 (the ++ operator is after the variable so the increment occurs after the assignment)

```
printf("\nThe value of num after using num++ is: %d", num4);
```

What you write inside your **printf** is not exact. You are not printing the value of **num** but **num1**, **num2**,...

As

```
num4 = num++;
```

**num4** is different than **num** (it's **num** minus one)

Comment: I'm using integers like 2 and etc. so is there a need for float? My only problem left is that the answers for ans3 and ans4 is 4 and not 3 as my input for num is 2. Did the value change halfway? How do I prevent that?

Comment: no you don't need float as long all your values are integers. Regarding the problem on the printed values of num3 and num4 you should ask this in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think you still have to use

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```

even for int since it's still reading numeric data.

I think your answer changed halfway as well after ans2 because you used `num2 = num +=1;`. The `+=` is like using `num = num + 1;`. Which would modify the value of num. So, ans3 and ans4 became different from what you expected. E.g. if you entered num as 2, ans 3 and ans4 would equal 4 instead of 3. If you want to get notified about this, you can put some print statements such as `printf("\n Just printing value of num at this moment: %d",num);` at various places in your code to observe the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are taking the input is wrong. You need to add an '&' sign before all the variables except for strings. So change the statement to `scanf("%d",&num);`

And also from reading your code,you want to initiate num1 if value of num=2.

`printf("When value of variable num is 2,\n")`

but your code does initiate it for any value of num. For avoiding that use an if loop as

```
printf("When value of variable num is 2,\n")
if(num==2)
{num1=num+1;}
else
{num1=0;
//or some other condition you wish
}
//and rest continues...
```